# Is .NET for Universal Windows Program a subset of .NET Core?

Tags: .net, win-universal-app, .net-core

My confusion is I read that UWP uses .NET Core, but there's a separate ".NET for UWP" API documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx). Also, I can't find some .NET Core features in my UWP project.

Comment: Have you read through the [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)? This may clear it up somewhat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET Core is a cross-platform subset of .NET that can be use to build apps for Windows, Linux, Mac, and yes, UWP.

UWP Api is also a subset of the .NET API, which can run on .NET Core.  It also has a number of API's that are unique to UWP.  UWP apps can be .NET core apps, but the reverse is not necessarily true.  Not all .NET core apps are UWP apps.

Just like there are API's for .NET Core that only apply to Linux, or Mac.

Comment: .NET Core is not the subset of .NET Framework , both are separate even if they have few same APIs , still they have different implementations.

Comment: @Ammar - I wasn't talking about the implementation, I was talking about the API's... the interfaces.

Answer (score 18):

Straight Answer: No it is not!

Long Answer: It's complicated

- `uap10.0` (UWP) and `netcoreapp1.0` (cross-platoform .NET Core) are competing app models / SDK / Platforms (whatever terminology Microsoft chooses to mention next). I use the target framework monikers (the technical terminology) here onwards to avoid confusions around the term ".NET Core". `uap10.0` focus on Windows based UI applications and `netcoreapp1.0` is basically console applications for cross platforms (which like any programs can run servers, like ASP.NET).
- The superset / subset question is tricky. They overlap. `uap10.0` implements the `netstandard1.4` and `netcoreapp1.0` implements the `netstandard1.6` (which is a strict superset to `netstandard1.4`) ([platform standard documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)). However, both application models add significant additional libraries to it (`uap10.0` adds e.g. the `Windows.*` libraries, while the library for `netcoreapp1.0` called `Microsoft.NETCore.App` ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App)) adds stuff like immutable collections, networking, filesystem, cryptography and other things which are not standardized (yet) across the .NET implementations).
- The terminology ".NET Core" is basically screwed up. The CLR which runs `uap10.0`/UWP was derived from Silverlight which labelled its runtime `coreclr`. The modern cross platform `netcoreapp1.0` uses a CLR derived from the UWP project. The same is true for the libraries which in all cases are `System.Runtime` based instead of `mscorlib` based.

**Update August 2019**

- By now there is still the same difference between `uap10.x` and `netcoreapp3.x`. However, they both implement the `netstandard2.x` (and so do mono and unity). The `netstandard2.x` subset is a significant API surface making most nuget packages compatible with both.
- to my understanding a big part of the winrt API surface will be accessible to `netcoreapp3.x` with their included COM support (covering winrt com and traditional COM). That makes the `netcoreapp3.x` intersection very significant. This is scheduled for later 2019.
- `netcoreapp3.0` will also support WPF and WinForms and other .NET Framework libraries. These will never be supported by `uap10.0`.
- The UWP technology stack (which are several layers) are now support packaging/store treatment for any kind of app (not only uap/winrt once).
- The real interesting stuff is coming with .NET 5 and 6. Java, WebAssembly and Swift interop, AOT compilation and MonoVM. The accessible library surface and the deployment locations will explode.

Comment: A great well thoughtout answer, I'd love to hear your explanation up to date with the current framework to make it easier to apply to the current downloads. It would also be cool if you have an understanding of the upcoming net core 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 14):

No, UWP is a distinct api that targets a different windowing model, replacing large parts of the traditional winapi.  You get a .NETCore dependency because the project templates in VS select it.  For a good reason, you can get the U in UWP (Universal Windows Platform) only from .NETCore, devices like phones and Hololens don't have the full .NET framework version available.  Trying to be competitive in mobile applications was a core reason for UWP.

UWP is a COM based api, basic reason why it works with languages like Javascript and C++.  Otherwise very well hidden, the traditional type library format of COM was replaced with .winmd, a format that is heavily based on the metadata format of .NET.  It can emulate features that COM cannot support, like generics, static methods and implementation inheritance.  The *language projection* that's required to get this emulation is built into the CLR.  Not much they could do to make exceptions work better.

You can use a UWP api in a desktop app as well.  Microsoft doesn't encourage that so you get no help from a project template.  Easy to fix with a text editor, add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to your .csproj file and now you can use Project > Add Reference and select a UWP contract.  Handy to take advantage of the device namespaces.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use UWP in a desktop app.  Any sources for additional info, like limitations or anything?  That sounds awesome.

Comment: Its a bit late to the original post - but to address the 'calling uwp from desktop' you can use the UWP Desktop package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop